# Load Forms up Smoother - How do I load my form before displaying?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I'm working on a project that has a mainform and then many other forms laid over it. Whenever I create a new form and lay it over the mainForm, I had an issue with flicker. All of my forms are set to not have a FormBorderStyle, but whenever I load the form, the border would flash for just a second before disappearing. I did some research on this and found a function that I was able to use that reduced the flickering by overriding the create parameters (see below)

```
 protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        //this is used to reduce the flicker created when loading a new form
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

And this works great to get rid of that flicker that occurs whenever I create the form, however it forces the form to need to resize. So what ends up happening is my screen flickers differently. This time it loads the form up to the original size, and THEN fills the screen, whereas I need it to load up all the information, and THEN display it to the screen.

[image: Picture loads the form...]

[image: Picture then resizes the form]

Does anyone know of a function that basically tells the form to wait until a certain point before showing itself?

I'm trying to make the program full screen and take up the entire space of the main monitor, and so I can't really do anything with starting the form out larger or something like that since it would just resize on smaller screens, and that still wouldn't get rid of the load - resize aspects.

I DO have all of the load functions overridden to change locations and sizes of all the forms so it fills the screen up correctly, could that be causing it?

Comment: Have you seen this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163630.aspx ?

Comment: How about loading the form with `Visible = False`, and setting it to `True` only after it has finished loading?

Comment: Uri Y beat me to it.. +1

Comment: Just gave the visible function a shot and it didn't work for me - when I'm creating a form, I'm already creating it invisibly, and then calling Form.Show(); to actually pull the form up. It seems that whenever I load the form, it loads to my default specs, and then when I show it it needs to resize.

Comment: This makes little sense.  Any resizing needs to be done in constructor or Load event.  The window becomes visible after that.  You could only have this problem if you do something that changes the size after that.  If you can't find that code then override OnResize() and set a breakpoint on it.